# Silverlight Twoway Binding and rolling back changes - how to?

Tags: silverlight, binding

I have simple SL user control.  A listbox which shows all customers and on the right a number of textboxes and comboboxes that are bound to the SelectedItem (Customer) in the listbox.  The SelectedItem bound to SelectedCustomer property.

I am looking for a pattern/methodology to deal with canceling changes made to the customer (in the bound textboxes and combo boxes).

The edit controls (textboxes and combo's) can be one or two way bound to the selecteditem of the listbox.
If they are two way bound, immediate changes in the textboxes are reflected in the listbox.  If they are oneway bound the changes in the textboxes are not reflected in the SelectedCustomer object.

At the bottom of the edit form i have typical Save, Cancel, Delete buttons.  The save button for instance would take the SelectedCustomer object (if twoway bound and I would send through service for saving on server).

If the textboxes are one way bound i have to capture somehow the textbox values and insert into some object for sending to the server for saving.

If I use twoway binding , and say the save operation fails...i have to set the SelectedCustomer values back to original values otherwise the client now continues to see data that has not been saved.

There must be an easy way of dealing with this type of scenario....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RIA Services with Entity Framework already provides this functionality, basically how RIA services works and you can do it too as follow.

Each class implements interface called IEditableObject, which provides methods BeginEdit/EndEdit and CancelEdit. And it also stores (copies) instance of same class with name "OriginalEntity" with same values that were loaded from server.

After the form shows up for user to modify, BeginEdit is called, which probably caches every property using reflection, in some sort of dictionary. If you call CancelEdit, then values from OriginalEntity are loaded back in object.

Upon some errors while saving changes, you can either refresh the entities from server (best way) or you can try loading properties back from OringalEntity property.

Comment: Good, so what I have done is created a partial class for my Customer class i.e. public partial class Customer : IEditableObject in the SL application.  Within the methods i provided code similar to that found here http://www.silverlight.net/learn/tutorials/silverlight-4/web-services-and-silverlight/#Exercise3

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't discard user changes, as that easily leads to user frustration. IMHO, the user should not be informed about connection problems by uncontrolled data rollbacks.

Comment: True, in my particular scenario the user is hitting button Cancel and so as a result i need to rollback edits made in the edit form as well as the listbox.